# Error Occures when generating NetworkAdapter.cs in Visual Studi

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I want to be able to disable a Network Adapter, using the Code which is shown on [this Site](http://web.archive.org/web/20120615012706/http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2008/06/24/HOWTODisableEnableNetworkConnectionsProgrammaticallyUnderVista.aspx).
When i enter `mgmtclassgen Win32_NetworkAdapter -p NetworkAdapter.cs` in my Command Promp I get an error message: `Error! Access to the Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\NetworkAdapter.cs" was not granted.`

Am I using a old version of this command, which is no longer working?

Comment: Please include the code itself with the instead of only providing the link, because the link can become broken.

Comment: The Problem is not the Code, its that the command (which i wrote into my question) doesn't work

Comment: If the code example has zero importance to your question then it needs to be removed.